# R : rename columns in function of data of a second dataframe (unblinding data)

Tags: r

**Context:**
I did a double-blind psychology experiment (which means that the participant nor the experiment new in which condition they were). There are two sessions : session1 and session2, and two condition SHAM and real tDCS.

**Main data set:** The data is structured as follows :

```
df<- structure(list(ID = 1:4, session1_Con_rt_mean = c(537.34, 541.9, 548.76, 
621.35), session1_Incon_rt_mean = c(646.83, 689.4, 614.57,  640.6), 
session2_Con_rt_mean = c(565.42, 547.23, 536.4, 564.15), 
session2_Incon_rt_mean = c(647.53, 660.68, 641.9, 606.52)), 
row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

>df
  ID session1_Con_rt_mean session1_Incon_rt_mean session2_Con_rt_mean session2_Incon_rt_mean
1  1               537.34                 646.83               565.42                 647.53
2  2               541.90                 689.40               547.23                 660.68
3  3               548.76                 614.57               536.40                 641.90
4  4               621.35                 640.60               564.15                 606.52
```

I have a set of variables that start with "session1" or "session2".

**Second data set:** In a different csv file, I have a database that tells me whether a participant was in the SHAM condition or in the REAL condition.

```
df2 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, session1 = c("SHAM","REAL","SHAM","SHAM"), 
session2 = c("REAL","SHAM","REAL","REAL")), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")

>df2
  ID session1 session2
1  1     SHAM     REAL
2  2     REAL     SHAM
3  3     SHAM     REAL
4  4     SHAM     REAL
```

**What I want to achieve:** I want to rename the columns (or create new ones ?) and fit the data properly. So basicly I think it would consist of remixing the data, going from a session1/session2 structure to REAL/SHAM structure.
Example : if participant 1 was in REAL in session1, then all the data of columns session1 go into rename REAL_nameofvariable columns.

Example of the result I'd like to achieve :

```
  ID SHAM_Con_rt_mean SHAM_Incon_rt_mean REAL_Con_rt_mean REAL_Incon_rt_mean
1  1           537.34             646.83           565.42             647.53
2  2           547.23             660.68           541.90             689.40
```

**Question:** How could I code this efficiently ?

*PS : please, ask any questions if I'm being unclear.*

Comment: @sindri_baldur Thank you for your comment. It's actually a .csv file, and I do my data analysis in R.  I'll rephrase my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could tidy the data, and join your two data tables to unblind subjects.

To tidy the data, consider converting your variables from wide to long.

Then, you can join the two tables based on ID number and `session`.

```
library(tidyverse)

tidy_main_data <- main_data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = c("session", ".value"), names_pattern = "(\\d)_(\\w+)")

tidy_blinding_table <- blinding_table %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = "session", names_pattern = "(\\d)")

left_join(tidy_main_data, tidy_blinding_table, by = c("ID", "session"))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
      ID session Con_rt_mean Incon_rt_mean value
   <int> <chr>         <int>         <int> <fct>
 1     1 1               491           439 SHAM 
 2     1 2               723           455 REAL 
 3     2 1               649           584 REAL 
 4     2 2               344           330 SHAM 
 5     3 1               330           438 REAL 
 6     3 2               271           930 SHAM 
 7     4 1               368           423 SHAM 
 8     4 2               143           536 REAL 
 9     5 1               460           511 REAL 
10     5 2               938           525 SHAM
```

**Edit**: And can `pivot_wider` if you'd like:

```
joined_tables <- left_join(tidy_main_data, tidy_blinding_table, by = c("ID", "session"))

joined_tables %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, names_from = "value", values_from = c("Con_rt_mean", "Incon_rt_mean"))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
     ID Con_rt_mean_SHAM Con_rt_mean_REAL Incon_rt_mean_SHAM Incon_rt_mean_REAL
  <int>            <int>            <int>              <int>              <int>
1     1              491              723                439                455
2     2              344              649                330                584
3     3              271              330                930                438
4     4              368              143                423                536
5     5              938              460                525                511
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(10)

main_data <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:5,
  session1_Con_rt_mean = sample(1:1000, 5, replace = T),
  session1_Incon_rt_mean = sample(1:1000, 5, replace = T),
  session2_Con_rt_mean = sample(1:1000, 5, replace = T),
  session2_Incon_rt_mean = sample(1:1000, 5, replace = T)
)

blinding_table <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:5,
  session1 = c("SHAM", "REAL", "REAL", "SHAM", "REAL"),
  session2 = c("REAL", "SHAM", "SHAM", "REAL", "SHAM")
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works perfectly. Edit : I saw you added pivot_wider in your answer in the meantime, thank you.